# c# System.Windows.Rect struct Width and Height

Tags: c#

If I do this:

```
Rect rc = new Rect(0, 0, 10, 5);
```

I am creating a rectangle at position 0, 0 with a width of 10 and height of 5.
So `rc.Width` is 10 and `rc.Height`is 5.

But how come `rc.Right` is 9 instead of 10 and `rc.Bottom` is 5 instead of 4?

Comment: Right and Bottom are coordinates, like Width and Height. Remember that the coordinate system is zero based. So horizontally, your rect spans (includes) the pixels at the X-coordinates 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. Do you see how you get a width of 10?

Comment: I am so sorry I wrote it wrong. I mean it should be 9 instead of 10 but it is showing as 10 (Neolisk has shown below).

Comment: @RexHui: Then this is normal. Right is by definition Left + Width. Similarly for Bottom. I was surprised at other answers, so I tested (always used Rectangle class myself, never Rect). See my updated answer, hopefully it answers your question.

Comment: @Neolisk: I was thinking in terms of drawing a rectangle on screen. But if Right is defined as Left + Width, then I understand now. Thanks!

Comment: yes, both you and Neolisk are right. Sorry for jumping to conclusions without validating them. Guess i should rather lean back and enjoy the long weekend... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Actually, [Rect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect(v=vs.110).aspx) also works as you expect, I tried in Visual Studio 2017:

[image]

Are you using some other `Rect`? Below is decompiled code for calculating Bottom:

```
/// <summary>
/// Bottom Property - This is a read-only alias for Y + Height
/// If this is the empty rectangle, the value will be negative infinity.
/// </summary>
public double Bottom
{
    get
    {
        if (IsEmpty)
        {
            return Double.NegativeInfinity;
        }

        return _y + _height; //notice it's just top + height, no magic
    }
}
```

**Old answer** - Use [Rectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle(v=vs.110).aspx). It works as you expect:

```
Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 5);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Because locations are zero based. The 3rd parameter defines the width in pixels, in this case, 10 pixels. So, it starts at zero, and is 10 pixels long, which means the rightmost location is at 9. The same principle applies to height as well, which explains the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the coordinate system is zero-based starts at `(0, 0)`.

So a rectangle with a width of 10 has its starting point at 0 and if you count out 10 units, the right-most coordinate will be 9.

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```